# React app gets 404 when fetching url with params

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In my app I have React-router like this:

```
const App = () => (
  <Router>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
    <Route path="/about" component={About} />
    <Route path="/searching/:term" component={Searching} />
  </Router>
 );

 export default App;
```

Every routes (with or without params) working fine with some handle (onClick, onChange, onSubmit, etc.). If I type url (route without param) to browser, for example mypage.com/about it's working. Routes with params (in above code is the third route) is not working. Everytime when I access to url with param, I get error 404. Could you help me how to fix it?

Thank you.

/* EDIT */

Added Searching component:

```
const Searching = (props) => (
<div>
    <PagesHeader />
    <Container className="pageContainer">
        <Row>
            <Col md={{size: 10, offset: 1}}>
               Searching result for: <b>{props.match.params.term}</b>
            </Col>
        </Row>
    </Container>
    <Footer />
</div>
);
export default Searching;
```

Comment: So when you go to `localhostOrWhatever:someport/searching/abcd` you get a 404?

Comment: Hello @AndrewLi. Yes, like you wrote.

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/q/27928372/5647260

Comment: Hmm, I think that it's not the same problem. I have a problem only with url with parameters. If I go to localhost:PORT/about it's working fine.

Comment: Why React-router version are you using?

Comment: Post the code of your `Searching` component. The react-router config is fine.

Comment: Hello @JamesGentes I edited my question with added `Searching` component.

Comment: That looks fine too. Are you using Express or something? The problem may be in your node configuration..

Comment: In this app I use only client routing without server, so I don't have any node configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the soultion for this. Problem was only with position of my bundle.js file, so I had to change path only.

Next problem with routing which I had was in production version of my app. I use React Router in version 4.2. Problem was only in production version if I put url to browser, it returns me 404.

So, when I linked to another component by click, everything was fine. When I copied/pasted url of some page, it returns me 404.

The best way for this should be routing on server part (Node.js, for example with Express.js). My application is fully with front-end routing and my hosting not support Node.js. Back-end (API) is in Laravel.

My solution is to add this code to `.htaccess` file on my hosting:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

The second solution is CDN like `surge.vs` or `GitHub Pages` [here is fantastic article for this](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/surge-vs-github-pages-deploying-a-create-react-app-project-c0ecbf317089).

Maybe it helps somebody.